# Git conflict during squashing in interactive rebase

Tags: git, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

I've the following git history

```
* bee55e9 (HEAD -> WM-290) - Jepessen : Little refactoring. (4 minutes ago)
* 1a4470a - Jepessen : Project refactoring (5 minutes ago)
* 399f769 - Jepessen : Added some documentation. (15 minutes ago)
* cb1055e - Jepessen : Another Test passed. (21 minutes ago)
* 549f147 - Jepessen : Another test passed. (24 minutes ago)
* b77c862 - Jepessen : First test passed. (29 minutes ago)
* d2c9d86 - Jepessen : Integer -> IntegerValue: Failing test added. (31 minutes ago)
* 678c0b1 - Jepessen : ExpressionTest added. (2 hours ago)
* b65284b - Jepessen : Refactored. (2 hours ago)
* 29ccc99 - Jepessen : Solution Refactored. (2 hours ago)
* 83f7a45 - Jepessen : Some Refactoring (2 hours ago)
* c33b81f - Jepessen : Integer class added. (2 hours ago)
* 1415bb4 - Jepessen : Leaf class added. (2 hours ago)
* a25da8b - Jepessen : Added Expression project (2 hours ago)
* aa9c4e8 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) - Jepessen : WMathTest C# solution added. (2 hours ago)
* b31dc4d - Jepessen : .gitignore updated. (2 hours ago)
* f7285b1 - Jepessen : Removed old files. (2 hours ago)
* 8d1213c - Jepessen : .gitignore updated. (23 hours ago)
* ed5a67a - Jepessen : WSchool project added. (24 hours ago)
```

I want to squash the `WM-290` branch into a single commit. I use the command

```
git rebase -i master
```

And in the interactive rebasing I write:

```
pick a25da8b Added Expression project
s 1415bb4 Leaf class added.
s c33b81f Integer class added.
s 83f7a45 Some Refactoring
s 29ccc99 Solution Refactored.
s b65284b Refactored.
s 678c0b1 ExpressionTest added.
s d2c9d86 Integer -> IntegerValue: Failing test added.
s b77c862 First test passed.
s 549f147 Another test passed.
s cb1055e Another Test passed.
s 399f769 Added some documentation.
s 1a4470a Project refactoring
s bee55e9 Little refactoring.
```

During rebasing I obtain the following error message:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        WMathTest/Expression/Expression.csproj
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
Could not apply 83f7a45... Some Refactoring
```

But if I use the command `git mergetool` I obtain the following message:

```
$ git mergetool
No files need merging
```

The only thing that I can do is to abort the rebasing.

Why there's a conflict, considering that the branch is on the top of the `master` branch, and how can I solve it if no files need merging?

EDIT:

During the conflict, this is the output of the command `git status`:

```
$ git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto aa9c4e8
Last commands done (5 commands done):
   s 83f7a45 Some Refactoring
   s c33b81f Integer class added.
  (see more in file .git/rebase-merge/done)
Next commands to do (11 remaining commands):
   s 83f7a45 Some Refactoring
   s 29ccc99 Solution Refactored.
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently rebasing branch 'test' on 'aa9c4e8'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   WMathTest/Expression/Expression.csproj

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 1):

(I assume the graph fragment at the top is the output of `git log --oneline --decorate` or similar.)

It's not immediately clear to me what got you *into* the situation, but the situation itself is clear enough:<sup>1</sup> at the point the interactive rebase fails, file `WMathTest/Expression/Expression.csproj` is in your work-tree, but is not in your index.

Presumably, commit `83f7a45` comprises (either consists of, or includes) the addition of a new file `WMathTest/Expression/Expression.csproj` that was not in the snapshot stored in commit `c33b81f Integer class added.`  However, what's in commit `83f7a45` does not match what is in your work-tree right now.  This—specifically, how this file got into your work-tree in the state it has right now, when it's in some of these intermediate commits—is the part that I find a bit unclear.  For this to be the case, that same file must *also* not be in commit `bee55e9 Little refactoring.`  (If it *were* in that commit, and not in `a25da8b Added Expression project`, Git would have removed it safely at the start of the rebase.  If it were in *both* `bee55e9` and `a25da8b`, Git would have *replaced* the work-tree file with the starting version, and again we'd not be in this situation.  The only remaining possibility is that it's not in *either* commit—not in the branch tip and not in the first `pick` commit—but is sitting around right now in the work-tree for some reason.  That, only you can explain.)

In any case, the underlying `git cherry-pick` operation that interactive rebase uses to pick-or-squash each commit into the current index and work-tree is failing because of this file.  There is no *merge conflict* with this file as it's not being *merged:* it's merely in the way of the rebase.

One solution would be to either commit it (make it tracked), or remove it from the work-tree, when on the tip of `WM-290`, so that either Git itself will remove it, or it's not sitting there being in the way.

Another is to skip all the rebase stuff.  If you simply want to make the current index contents become a single commit at the tip of branch `WM-290`, with that single commit having as its parent, the commit that is currently the tip of `master`, you can just do:

```
git reset --soft master
git commit
```

and write an all-new commit message (note that this won't build up the intermediate squashed commit messages for you the way `git rebase -i` does).  The `--soft` tells Git not to touch the index (nor of course the work-tree), so the index continues to contain the same snapshot it had when `WM-290` referred to commit `bee55e9`.  This `reset` merely moves the branch label back, so that the next new commit has `aa9c4e8` as its parent:

```
                      newnewn        <-- WM-290
                     /
...--b31dc4d--aa9c4e8                <-- master
                     \
                      a25da8b--1415bb4--...--bee55e9   [was WM-290]
```

The *snapshot* for commit `newnewn` (whose ID we don't know yet) will be the *same* as the snapshot for `bee55e9`.  The *parent* commit will be `aa9c4e8`.  That's what `git reset --soft` does: keep the *index* unchanged, so that a new commit will re-use it, but move the branch name, so that the new commit will go after some other commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, clear to someone who has spent years <strike>fighting</strike> working with Git. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try when I'll have the pc on my hands again. I don't know why I've this problem, at every commit I've added and committed everything. I'm used to do a `git status` always before and after a commit, and I didn't have any untracked file during commits... I can't understand why I've this situation...